# DAX to lookup date in start date column in ssas tabular model

Tags: sql-server, excel, dax, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

I have two (2) tables in model design,

---Main Table(X):-

```
     title     start date
     Test1     01.01.2010
     Test1     01.01.2015
     Test1     01.01.1900
     Test2     01.01.2018
     .
     .
     test1     01.01.9999
```

---Calculated table(Y):-

```
      Date
   01.01.2010
   01.02.2010
   01.03.2010
   01.04.2010
   .
   .
   .
   01.01.9999
```

I have populated calculated table using below formula

```
=CALENDAR(MINX(X,[START_DATE]),MAXX(X,[START_DATE]))
```

Ideally, I would like to add calculated new column to Table Y which looks up  date(Y) with start date from Table X means matching date into new column.

----New column(New Date) in Table Y

```
  01.01.2010
  01.01.9999
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't quite follow how the new column works. Why does it only have two values ?

Comment: I am trying to insert matching rows into new column and I want to show as date column in excel.